# How do I test modelform validation when the model includes a FileField?

Tags: django, django-forms

I took an age looking for the answer to this so now I've figured it out I'm putting it here for future users. I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.5 but this answer should also work for Python 3+ and Django 1.6+

### The problem

I have a model that includes a `FileField`. I'm using a `ModelForm` to let users add instances of this model. I want all my app's code to be under testing, including any forms. Passing file paths, file objects or byte strings in a data dictionary does not result in a valid form.

### The question

How do I test validation on a `ModelForm` including a `FileField`?

Answer (score 1):

You can infer the answer from [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files). The trick is that you don't pass the `FileField` data in the same dictionary as the rest of your form data. Instead, your `test_forms.py` should look something like:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.test import TestCase


class CorrespondenceFormTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def test_correspondence_form_with_good_data(self):
        data = {
            'direction': 'OU',
            'incoming_mail_type': '',
            'outgoing_mail_type': 'CL',
        }
        file_data = {
            'correspondence_file': SimpleUploadedFile('test.txt', 'Hi!')
        }
        form = CorrespondenceForm(data, file_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

This will pass. You can now write additional tests for the things you want to fail with confidence that they fail for the right reason.